# Concatenate String in String Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, string

I want to place a string within a string. Basically in pseudo code:

```
"first part of string" + "(varying string)" + "third part of string"
```

How can I do this in objective-c? Is there a way to easily concatenate in obj-c? Thanks!

Comment: Lots of answers below, [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithFormat:) is the documentation on stringWithFormat.

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Just google '%@'!", @"http://www.google.hu/search?q=nsstring+class+reference&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari"];`

Comment: @rdelmar not really. All of these answers are perfectly valid and should be upvoted.

Comment: With the improvements they added with quickly initializing NSDictionary and NSArray, I'm surprised they haven't simplified string concatenation yet.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Yes, do

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"first part %@ second part", varyingString];
```

For concatenation you can use `stringByAppendingString`

```
NSString *str = @"hello ";
str = [str stringByAppendingString:@"world"]; //str is now "hello world"
```

For multiple strings

```
NSString *varyingString1 = @"hello";
NSString *varyingString2 = @"world";
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", varyingString1, varyingString2];
//str is now "hello world"
```

Comment: Would this work for numerous strings? Like have several %@ and do varyingString, varyingString2?

Answer (score 13):

Variations on a theme:

```
NSString *varying = @"whatever it is";
NSString *final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"first part %@ third part", varying];
```

---

```
NSString *varying = @"whatever it is";
NSString *final = [[@"first part" stringByAppendingString:varying] stringByAppendingString:@"second part"];
```

---

```
NSMutableString *final = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"first part"];
[final appendFormat:@"%@ third part", varying];
```

---

```
NSMutableString *final = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"first part"];
[final appendString:varying];
[final appendString:@"third part"];
```

Answer (score 10):

```
NSString * varyingString = ...;
NSString * cat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%@%@",
  "first part of string",
  varyingString,
  @"third part of string"];
```

or simply `-[NSString stringByAppendingString:]`

Answer (score 6):

You would normally use `-stringWithFormat` here.

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", @"some text", stringVariable, @"some more text"];
```

Comment: This is really the best way when you have a large string that you are building for let's say an XML.

Answer (score 4):

Iam amazed that none of the top answers pointed out that under recent Objective-C versions (after they added literals), you can concatenate just like this:

```
@"first" @"second"
```

And it will result in:

```
@"firstsecond"
```

You can not use it with NSString objects, only with literals, but it can be useful in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

Just do

```
NSString* newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"first part of string (%@) third part of string", @"foo"];
```

This gives you

```
@"first part of string (foo) third part of string"
```

Answer (score 1):

simple one:

```
[[@"first" stringByAppendingString:@"second"] stringByAppendingString:@"third"];
```

if you have many STRINGS to Concatenate, you should use `NSMutableString` for better performance