# Xcode: How do I get a textLabel to display addition static text that is being entered in the textField?

Tags: xcode5, textfield

I am a Xcode newbie, please help.

So I know how to change the text in Label box by with a text field:

self.textLabel.text = self.textField.text

The question is: how do I add static text to text that is being entered?

Like if in the textField a name is entered, how do get the label box to display a "Hi," then whatever text that was entered?

What do I have to put in front of "self.textField.text" after the "=" sign ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concatenate 2 Strings.
Here are some clues:

[Shortcuts in Objective-C to concatenate NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510269/how-do-i-concatenate-strings)

[Concatenate String in String Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971945/concatenate-string-in-string-objective-c)

[Simple string concatenation in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853865/simple-string-concatenation-in-objective-c)

So:

```
self.textLabel.text = [@"Hi" stringByAppendingString: self.textField.text]
```

or

```
[textLabel setStringValue: [@"Hi" stringByAppendingString: self.textField.text]];
```